# How to reset build number in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins and Gradle to build my java project.

Every time I build my project, I get a new build number on the Jenkins screen.

The following is my Jenkins build info:

```
Success > Console Output  #96   03-Jan-2014 15:35:08    
Success > Console Output  #95   03-Jan-2014 15:27:29     
Failed > Console Output  #94    03-Jan-2014 15:26:16     
Failed > Console Output  #93    03-Jan-2014 15:25:01     
Failed > Console Output  #92    03-Jan-2014 15:23:50     
Success > Console Output  #91   03-Jan-2014 12:42:32    
Success > Console Output  #90   03-Jan-2014 12:02:45
```

I want to reset the Jenkins build number like:

```
Success > Console Output  #1    03-Jan-2014 12:02:45
```

How can I reset the build number in Jenkins?

Answer (score 184):

Can be easier done from groovy script console .
Go to http://your-jenkins-server/script
In script window enter:

```
item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("your-job-name-here")
//THIS WILL REMOVE ALL BUILD HISTORY
item.builds.each() { build ->
  build.delete()
}
item.updateNextBuildNumber(1)
```

Comment: or via cli
`java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://jenkins.example.com groovysh \
  'jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("job-name").updateNextBuildNumber(1021)'`

Comment: This is definitely the best answer. You dont even need the delete loop if you only want to set the number.

Comment: For some reason this only performs the delete on the latest build, however the following did work for me:

`echo "deleting all builds of ${jobName}"
    item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("${jobName}")
    for (build in item.builds){
        build.delete();
    }
    item.updateNextBuildNumber(1)`

Comment: A noob question.. how i know exact job-name.

Comment: @AmmarMujeeb go to your Jenkins dashboard and you'll see the job name there. You can also go to `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/` on Linux and the name of the directory there is the exact job name

Comment: I've posted this as an answer in its own right, but since it probably won't make it to the top of the heap ... the `build` object has a `number` property, upon which you can condition, so you can delete just a partial segment of the build history, to rollback past a few builds you want to delete.

Comment: This worked except running build afterwards fails and produces errors in log: WARNING: A new build could not be created in job <job-name>
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JENKINS-27530: cannot create a build with number 1 since that (or higher) is already in use among [xxx, xxx, xxx, ... <build numbers from builds that were just deleted>]

Comment: It is possible to store the script in Jenkins -> Scriptler, including parameter and description for later re-use. This requires to add import line in the script:
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
...

Comment: For jobs in folders: item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("folder/jobname")

Answer (score 64):

From [here](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Possible-to-remove-all-build-data-and-reset-build-1-td1458487.html)

> Given your Hudson job is named FooBar,
>
> - rename FooBar to FooBar-Copy
> - create a new job named FooBar, using 'Copy existing job' option, from FooBar-Copy
> - delete FooBar-Copy

Answer (score 38):

- First wipeout workspace and get rid of previous builds.

  - On the server navigate to
    the job dir eg. 'var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myJob' delete the
    workspace & build dirs as well as any polling files, lastSuccessful,
    lastStable files etc. You should only have config.xml and
    lastBuildNumber.
  - Shut down jenkins using something like **service jenkins stop**
  - Edit the file called **nextBuildNumber**, inserting 1 instead of the current build number
  - Start up jenkins again,  **service jenkins start**
  - Log into jenkins and go to your job and hit build. Should start building job#1

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

If you want set the next build number, there is plugin "NextBuildNumber" for that. But this will not work in your case because the build number you need, which is 1, is lesser than your current build number.

Here need to wipe out all the previous builds first. You can do this by running this simple script
**Go to -> Manage Jenkins -> Script console**

```
// change this variable to match the name of the job whose builds you want to delete
def jobName = "Your Job Name"
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName)
job.getBuilds().each { it.delete() }
```

Now you can set next build number to 1 and run the build. It will start with **1**. :)
Its that simple.

**Update - Jenkins now has a Purge Job History plugin to get this done in easiest way.** Checkout the page for more details - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Purge+Job+History+Plugin

Answer (score 6):

To more generally reset your build number to `N` (where `N` is not necessarily 1):

- Delete any existing builds where `buildNumber >= N`.
- Edit `Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/jobs/yourjob/nextBuildNumber`. Set the number it contains to `N`.
- From Jenkins, select `Manage Jenkins -> Reload Configuration from Disk`.

Comment: Make sure you read this defect before Selecting "Reload configuration from disk"  -- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32984

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on the accepted answer, here's how to do it for all projects at once:

```
Jenkins.instance.allItems.each() { 
  item -> item.builds.each() { 
    build -> build.delete()
  }
  item.updateNextBuildNumber(1)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As an extention of @antweiss's excellent answer, we can actually go further ...

There's no need to delete the full Build History, if you don't want to, you can simply roll back time, to a prior point:

```
resetNumberTarget = 14
item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("Project Name [from project Dashboard]")
//println(item)

item.builds.each() { build ->
  //println(build)
  //println(build.number)

  if(build.number >= resetNumberTarget)
  {
    //println("About to Delete '" + build + "'")    
    build.delete()  
  }
}

item.updateNextBuildNumber(resetNumberTarget)
```

If you want a dummy run, to check what it's going to do, without actually doing it, simply comment out the `build.delete()` and `item.updateNextBuildNumber(resetNumberTarget)` lines and uncomment the various print commands.

---

Documentation:
Details of these objects were hard to find, but I identified the following:

- `item` is a [FreeStyleProject](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/FreeStyleProject.html) (or possibly, just any type of [Abstract Project](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractProject.html)?)
- `build` appears to be a [Run](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Run.html), thus exposing a [number](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Run.html#number) property and inheritting a [delete()](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Job.html#delete--) method from [Job](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Job.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use Purge Job History plugin (Jenkins >= 2.176.1)

https://plugins.jenkins.io/purge-job-history/

Comment: some way to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `nexBuildNumber` plug-in or simply modify `nexBuildNumber` file to reset build number.
Following are the steps that you need to perform:

- Go to `.jenkins/Jobs/<YourJobName>/build/`, take backup of this folder(if you need for future use) and delete **build** folder.

> Note: Once you clean up old builds, you lose build histories and they
>   are no longer available on the Jenkins dashboard.

- Reload the configuration(Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins).
- Set next build version to 1 by either using the Next Build Number plug-in or modifying the `nextBuildNumber` file in yourjob directory.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried the above solution and getting the following error.,

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: builds for
> class:
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject.

So I tried this,

```
item = Jenkins.get().getItem("Job Name")
jobs = item.getAllJobs()
jobs.each() { item -> 
  builds = item.getBuilds()
  builds.each() { b -> 
    b.delete()
  }
  item.updateNextBuildNumber(1)

}
```

and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is variation of @antweiss answer for multi-branch pipeline

```html
items = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("your-job-name-here").getItems()
//THIS WILL REMOVE ALL BUILD HISTORY
items.collectMany { it.builds }.each { build ->
  build.delete()
}
items.each {
  it.updateNextBuildNumber(1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins script(Test on `Jenkins 2.387.3`):

```
def jobName = "<YOUR_PIPELINE_NAME>"
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName)
job.getBuilds().each { it.delete() }
job.updateNextBuildNumber(1)
```

Delete all build history and reset build number.

Answer (score -1):

To reset build numbers of all jobs:

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(AbstractProject.class).each {
    item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(it.fullName)
    //THIS WILL REMOVE ALL BUILD HISTORY
    item.builds.each() { build ->
        build.delete()
    }
    item.updateNextBuildNumber(1)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found an easy way to do this.

1. Wipe out your work space.
2. Go to each builds which saved on Jenkins and delete it.
3. Set build number to 1 then build.

Jenkins use previous build to determine the next build number, if build number you input is lower than previous build number, Jenkins will automatically increase your build number to higher than previous build. So here we just