# Reset the Jenkins build number to 1 for a Multibranch Pipeline job

Tags: ios, jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

Currently I am using the incremented build number provided by Jenkins for the release version of our iOS and Android app.  Product/dev drive the release numbers.  Once the feature branch is merged into master, a build is automatically kicked off and if the release number is incremented, I want to reset the build number back to 1.  For example if 5.0.1 (5) is the current market release and dev merges a feature branch into master with a greater release number, like 5.0.2, I want to reset the build number back to 1 so that the app version is now 5.0.2 (1).  My Jenkins is on a Linux server that uses a Mac OS X agent for building our iOS app.  How do I reset the build number back to 1 after I have kicked off the build, checked out the source code, and checked to see if the build should be reset?

Comment: None of these solutions from this thread are working for Jenkins ver. 2.46.2:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901791/how-to-reset-build-number-in-jenkins

Comment: Or this: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/216114978-How-to-set-next-build-number-in-Pipeline-job