# How to reset build numbers from Linux Jenkins master?

Tags: linux, jenkins

I have a Linux Jenkins master and one windows slave. I want all the current projects build numbers to be reset, and next time when I start the build it should start from number 1.

How to do that in Linux master? Please provide me the steps to reset build numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Jenkins build number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645430/changing-jenkins-build-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the groovy script console as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901791/how-to-reset-build-number-in-jenkins).

Go into your master Jenkins instance http://your_jenkins_url/script and run this:

```
item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("Your Project Name")
//THIS WILL REMOVE ALL BUILD HISTORY
item.builds.each() { build ->
  build.delete()
}
item.updateNextBuildNumber(1)
```

> I've tested it in my local setup and it worked:

[image: run_groovy_script]

> Results:

[image: results]