# Forcing jenkins to start the build number at x

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way in Jenkins to force the build number to start at 199 for example?

Since we have used cruise control for a number of years, I would like the build number is to continue from there if possible.

Comment: Share your build infor. This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901791/how-to-reset-build-number-in-jenkins

Comment: Do You need to start all jobs from that number as starting.
I think you can use Next Build Number Plugin in jenkins to start the second build from that number.

Comment: convert that to an answer  Chandra Sekhar

Answer (score 0):

Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49053851/1662268

```
resetNumberTarget = 14
item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("Project Name [from project Dashboard]")
//println(item)

item.builds.each() { build ->
  //println(build)
  //println(build.number)

  if(build.number >= resetNumberTarget)
  {
    //println("About to Delete '" + build + "'")    
    build.delete()  
  }
}

item.updateNextBuildNumber(resetNumberTarget)
```